# Looping until find some pixels with the same colors in canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to find a red color for example on a canvas, let's say I have a square painted on canvas, so I'd like to know the way to loop through that square and when I detect it get the x and y from now I have this :

```
var imgData = context.getImageData(face.x-1, face.y-1, 15+2, 15+2);
var pixels = imgData.data;

for (var i = 0; n = pixels.length, i < n; i += 4) {
    var red = pixels[i];
    var green = pixels[i+1];
    var blue = pixels[i+2];
    var alpha = pixels[i+3];
    //red color
    if(red == 255 && green == 0 && blue == 0){
         //fired when color is red
    }
```

*Note: face.x and face.y is the X and Y to position an image*

How can I do to loop the square let's say it's all black but 5 pixels that are red, I want to detect where is it and get the X and Y from the image in canvas

This is my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srs6zj3p/1/)(I'm trying to find a red color for example on a canvas, let's say I have a square painted on canvas, so I'd like to know the way to loop through that square and when I detect it get the x and y from now I have this :

```
var imgData = context.getImageData(face.x-1, face.y-1, 15+2, 15+2);
var pixels = imgData.data;

for (var i = 0; n = pixels.length, i < n; i += 4) {
    var red = pixels[i];
    var green = pixels[i+1];
    var blue = pixels[i+2];
    var alpha = pixels[i+3];
    //red color
    if(red == 255 && green == 0 && blue == 0){
         //fired when color is red
    }
```

*Note: face.x and face.y is the X and Y to position an image*

How can I do to loop the square let's say it's all black but 5 pixels that are red, I want to detect where is it and get the X and Y from the image in canvas

I've put this

```
img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/x9uJH7a.gif";
imgCara.src = "https://i.imgur.com/vJJlYw2.png";
```

But that's only a test to show you what I'm trying to do (those img are the ones I'm using on my project) but I can't see it on jsfiddle...

I tried to position with

```
var w = cara.x-1 + ((i / 4) % (imgData.width));
var z = cara.y-1 + Math.floor((i /4)/(imgData.width));
```

But doesn't work.

### Edit

I faced with this issue...

I've created this to save the x and y:

```
var xy={x:2,y:2};
```

Then I adapted your loop :

```
function findMatchingXY(R,G,B,tolerance){
// get the pixel data of the canvas
var data=context.getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height).data;
// loop through all pixels
for(var y=0;y<img.width;y++){
    for(var x=0;x<img.height;x++){
        // find the pixel data from the data[] rgba array
        //     representing the pixel at [x,y]
        var n=(y*img.width+x)*4;
        // compare this pixel's color channels with the targets
        var matchesRedTarget=Math.abs(R-data[n])<tolerance;
        var matchesGreenTarget=Math.abs(G-data[n+1])<tolerance;
        var matchesBlueTarget=Math.abs(B-data[n+2])<tolerance;
        // does this pixel match the target
        if(data[n+3]>30 && matchesRedTarget
            && matchesGreenTarget && matchesBlueTarget){
            // return the x,y of the first matching pixel
            return({x:x,y:y});
        }
    }}
// no matching pixels found, return null
return(null);
}
```

and in chrome it says :

> maze.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null

Comment: well, how sure are you from the perfect color? there are some libraries available that help you track down when a color is mostly red or green or blue. The red we see is mostly not `#ff0000`. However, since you say you want to find the non matching pixels, it might be easier to first decide which color is there all the time, and return all other pixels that are not of that defined color type. For the rest, you would have to check how you could scale the rgb input values to "catch" the matching red ones (so, eg: `#cf3030` is also still red, just a bit more "nuanced")

Comment: Hmmm now you can answer my question please? I accept all of your advices, but I'm trying to know how to make a loop to go through all of the pixels of the image until get the X and Y when I found a red pixel

Comment: well, your image data is a block of 17 columns *4 (1 byte per pixel) per row (and you have 17 rows), so, your `(i / 4) % 17` is your x position and your y position is `Math.floor((i / 4) / 17)`

Comment: And the loop how do I create it?

Comment: Sorry, is your question simply how to repeat the searching process over your full canvas until you have found the block that contains the red pixel? Cause in your question you demonstrate that you understand all of these things? No matter how many times I read the title and question, i'm not really sure what you mean / want to do...

Comment: I have the image of the maze ok? So I want to loop the image until I found a red pixel so then getting the X and Y I can position the cara.x and cara.y sorry if you don't understand something feel free to ask and I'll try to explain it better.... but now I think it's clear.  Since start I put cara.x = 2 and cara.y = 2 just for test, but now I just want to put the cara.x and cara.y where the red pixel is

Comment: If the purpose of detecting the red color is to detect if the player is on top of some objects, then there are better ways - f.ex. create and track an object representing the red color so you only have to compare the player position with the object position.

Comment: **Is this your question:** How can I tell if my smiley-face is colliding with a wall-side in my maze image?

Comment: @markE No, the result I want to do is put my smiley-face in front of the red wall-side dynamically since I don't know where is this "wall", you got me?

Comment: @K3N Read what I told to markE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I'm only 51% sure I understand your question, I'll leave this example code and hope that it helps you either answer or clarify your question. The key part of the code is the `findMatchingXY` function -- which I annotated to show how it works.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var size=15;
var $xy=$('#xy');
var targetRed=255;
var targetGreen=255;
var targetBlue=187;
var tolerance=5;

ctx.fillStyle='black';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);

$('#place').on('click',function(){
    // calc a random x,y and draw a 15x15 rect there
    var x=Math.random()*(cw-size);
    var y=Math.random()*(ch-size);
    ctx.fillStyle='black';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.fillStyle='rgb('+targetRed+','+targetGreen+','+targetBlue+')';
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,15,15);
});

$('#find').on('click',function(){
    var xy=findMatchingXY();
    if(xy){
        $xy.text('Found the matching rect at x='+xy.x+', y='+xy.y);
    }else{
        $xy.text('There is no matching rect');
    }
});

$('#place').trigger('click');


function findMatchingXY(){
    // get the pixel data of the canvas
    var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;
    // loop through all pixels
    for(var y=0;y<ch;y++){
    for(var x=0;x<cw;x++){
        // find the pixel data from the data[] rgba array
        //     representing the pixel at [x,y]
        var n=(y*cw+x)*4;
        // compare this pixel's color channels with the targets
        var matchesRedTarget=Math.abs(targetRed-data[n])<tolerance;
        var matchesGreenTarget=Math.abs(targetGreen-data[n+1])<tolerance;
        var matchesBlueTarget=Math.abs(targetBlue-data[n+2])<tolerance;
        // does this pixel match the target
        if(data[n+3]>30 && matchesRedTarget 
                && matchesGreenTarget && matchesBlueTarget){
            // return the x,y of the first matching pixel
            return({x:x,y:y});
        }
    }}
    // no matching pixels found, return null
    return(null);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='place'>Randomly place a rect</button>
<button id='find'>Find the randomly placed rect</button><br>
<h4 id='xy'>Place a target-color rect then find it.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=100></canvas>
```

**[ Addition: example using the maze image ]**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var $xy=$('#xy');
var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/mazeRed.png";
function start(){
    cw=canvas.width=img.width;
    ch=canvas.height=img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    var xy=findMatchingXY(255,47,47,10);
    if(xy){
        $xy.text('Found the matching pixel at x='+xy.x+', y='+xy.y);
    }else{
        $xy.text('There is no matching pixel');
    }    
}


function findMatchingXY(targetRed,targetGreen,targetBlue,tolerance){
    // get the pixel data of the canvas
    var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;
    // loop through all pixels
    for(var y=0;y<ch;y++){
    for(var x=0;x<cw;x++){
        // find the pixel data from the data[] rgba array
        //     representing the pixel at [x,y]
        var n=(y*cw+x)*4;
        // compare this pixel's color channels with the targets
        var matchesRedTarget=Math.abs(targetRed-data[n])<tolerance;
        var matchesGreenTarget=Math.abs(targetGreen-data[n+1])<tolerance;
        var matchesBlueTarget=Math.abs(targetBlue-data[n+2])<tolerance;
        // does this pixel match the target
        if(data[n+3]>30 && matchesRedTarget 
                && matchesGreenTarget && matchesBlueTarget){
            // return the x,y of the first matching pixel
            return({x:x,y:y});
        }
    }}
    // no matching pixels found, return null
    return(null);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id='xy'>Finding red line in maze</h4><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=100></canvas>
```

Comment: Ya maybe that's the 50% of the answer... but if you see my image you'll see a red line that means the entrance of the maze so I want to know how do I loop the image to find that red line to place the smile in front of it

Comment: See this is the [image](https://i.imgur.com/x9uJH7a.gif) so I want to find the red line and place the smile face where this redline is

Comment: How can I make a look to find this redline? I get it how can I place the smileface with the X and Y with your example but I only need this 50% more

Comment: Ah, I (now!) see the barely visible red line on the right side of the maze. OK, the code I've given finds the leftmost & topmost target (red) pixel on the canvas. My demo finds the top-left of a square, but you can use the exact same code to find the top-left pixel of the maze line. So you don't need different code, just use the answer's `findMatchingXY` to find your red line. Cheers!

Comment: Where it find the top-left? because I see your demo and it moves randomly and then it shows the x and y...

Comment: And I'm seeing the for loop mine and yours and it's "different" I see I see some math.abs and my loop doesn't have this, did you check the JsFiddle?

Comment: Focus on `findMatchingXY` rather than my demo which finds the yellow-ish square -- that's just a demo to exercise `findMatchingXY`! In your app, set the `targetRed, targetGreen, targetBlue & tolerance` variables to your desired search color (eg pure red would be 255,0,0 respectively). The tolerance is how far off the target colors you're willing to allow (eg if the color is red-ish rather than pure red). I pulled your maze into Photoshop and your target colors are red=255, green=43, blue=51. I've posted another demo finding your reddish line in your maze image. Good luck with your project!

Comment: wow you are a genius.... thanks mate, tomorrow I'll let you know if i solved it or not, from now I'll accept your answer since I know that with your answer I can deal... thanks a lot! :D

Comment: `findMatchingXY` will return `null` if there are no matching pixels on the canvas, so I suspect you're searching for target colors that aren't on the canvas. For example, your `https://i.imgur.com/x9uJH7a.gif` image does not contain pure red (255,0,0). In fact, the reddish color is (255,43,51). And the greenish color is (51,170,51).